# React Native Expo: Native crash

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

Hope all are safe and good.

I'm a learn of React Native.
I created my first ever mobile app using React Native expo.
I released the same for Internal testing in google play console successfully.
After I received below error,

```
Crashes and ANRs

Native crash

Error Issue 1 of 1 Detected on 1 device during testing

Stack trace: Native crash of com.sanMobiApp.covid19

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/blueline/blueline:9/PQ3A.190801.002/5670241:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'MP1.0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 17696, tid: 17960, name: Thread-5  >>> com.sanMobiApp.covid19 <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Cannot get a dirty matrix!'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000004628  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
    x4  feff71647164636d  x5  feff71647164636d  x6  feff71647164636d  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  0000000000000083  x9  00000073aa1790a0  x10 fffffff87ffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000018  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 ffffffffff000000  x15 ffffffffffffffff
    x16 00000073aa1b32c8  x17 00000073aa0f0dcc  x18 0000007308f3435a  x19 0000000000004520
    x20 0000000000004628  x21 0000000014b14ce0  x22 0000000014b14d10  x23 0000000014b14ce0
    x24 0000000014b14790  x25 0000000013309a50  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000000
    x28 0000000014b14ce0  x29 0000007308f34a90
    sp  0000007308f34a50  lr  00000073aa0e594c  pc  00000073aa0e5974
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000021974  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
    #01 pc 0000000000008090  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+296)
    #02 pc 00000000000fedf0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_view_RenderNode_getTransformMatrix(long, long)+120)
    #03 pc 00000000003d7c88  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.graphics.Matrix.nPostConcat [DEDUPED]+72)
    #04 pc 0000000000b7b420  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.RenderNode.getMatrix+64)
    #05 pc 0000000000c70d18  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.View.getMatrix+104)
    #06 pc 0000000000d35524  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect+228)
    #07 pc 0000000000d35928  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect+1256)
    #08 pc 0000000000d35928  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect+1256)
    #09 pc 0000000000d35928  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect+1256)
    #10 pc 0000000000d35928  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect+1256)
    #11 pc 0000000000d35928  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3cd000) (android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect+1256)
    #12 pc 0000000000057c14  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
```

Can you please help me to clear this error to push to production.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: I'm also having this issue `'Cannot get a dirty matrix!'` Have you find a solution?

Comment: for me it is worked after restarting the application.